# How to parse file name in Java?

Tags: java

I have a java file path

`/opt/test/myfolder/myinsidefolder/myfile.jar`

I want  to replace the  file path  to
here root path will remain same but want to change file name from `myfile.jar` to `Test.xml`

`/opt/test/myfolder/myinsidefolder/Test.xml`

How can i do this in java any help?

Answer (score 11):

## Using Java 9+

```
Path jarPath = Paths.get("/opt/test/myfolder/myinsidefolder/myfile.jar");
Path xmlPath = jarPath.resolveSibling("Test.xml");
```

## Using Java 8 and older

```
File myfile = new File("/opt/.../myinsidefolder/myfile.jar");
File test = new File(myfile.getParent(), "Test.xml");
```

Or, if you prefer working with strings only:

```
String f = "/opt/test/myfolder/myinsidefolder/myfile.jar";
f = new File(new File(f).getParent(), "Test.xml").getAbsolutePath();

System.out.println(f); // /opt/test/myfolder/myinsidefolder/Test.xml
```

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [Java Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/overview-summary.html) [FilenameUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) class.

That has numerous methods for *reliably* disassembling and manipulating filenames across different platforms (it's worth looking at for many other useful utilities too).

Comment: IMHO, if a third party lib does what you want o do, use that lib. Especially when it comes from apache. And even more so when the libs name starts with "commons".

Comment: But don't add a third party lib for something this simple that can be accomplished in a single line of standard JDK code (yes i know the answers have 2 or 3 lines, but those could be combined since most likely the intermediate parent file variables are not needed after the new file creation).

Answer (score 2):

```
File f = new File("/opt/test/myfolder/myinsidefolder/myfile.jar");
File path = f.getParentFile();
File xml = new File(path, "Test.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

A more direct approach using only JRE available class [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) :

```
String parentPath = new File("/opt/test/myfolder/myinsidefolder/myfile.jar").getParent();
new File(parentPath, "Test.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

To rename the file you can use Files.move from java.nio.file.Files

```
File oldFile=new File("/opt/test/myfolder/myinsidefolder/myfile.jar");
File newFile=new File(oldFile.getParent+"/"+"Test.xml");
try
{
  Files.move(oldFile.toPath(),newFile.toPath());
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
  System.err.println("File was not renamed!");
}
```